# Limited space for texts

Tags: forms

The site we are working in is done in metro design style. Some of the content is generated by user. We have quite big font size and very little space for Titles, Descriptions, Headings which will be created by user. If there will be only "w" in the title, only 17 signs fit in, if other letters are used (not so wide) more signs will be available.

The question is: how to limit length of titles, descriptions and headings?

Comment: What do you mean by 'how' in this situation? You mean actually restricting them from doing so?

Comment: I mean what kind of limitation to implement? Maximum sign quantity? Maximum width?

Comment: What actually happens if there are more characters than there is space for? Does it wrap? Do the extra characters just not display? Is there going to be issues if you do choose to wrap the text? As K. suggests, this is all stuff that should have been taken into account when the site was planned and designed. 17 characters is very small, your title is short by UX.SE standards, but it is still 24 characters long. I think you should go back to the drawing board and plan in decent length titles rather than just hacking what has been built to provide workarounds for not displaying them.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about implementation rather than UX

Answer (score 1):

- You could fade the title at the right border of the tile. So it would
  be obvious for user that there is a long text. It's an easiest way.
  [image]
- You could also use javascript to calculate maximum visible part of the title.
- You could also transform your weakness to strength. Make it your point, limit to 25 symbols (like the limits of Twitter)!

Answer (score 0):

You should had this in mind when you started the design.

Now the only things you can do is forcing the user to use short descriptions and titles *or* using automatically generated ellipses. Both suboptimal solutions.

Comment: I did. The question is how to limit the length? 15 signs? 20 signs? 25 signs? The amount of signs that fit in depends on which signs are used, because signs have different width

Comment: Then it's more an implementation question than an UX question. Because your UX decision of forcing the user to use less chars has already been made.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should do it not by limit the number of the characters, but instead of that you should cut the headline with CSS text-overflow: ellipsis.

Additionally you can provide the user the full information with a tooltip (mouseover) with the entire headline.